# How to Change Button Foreground and Background When Pressed and Released

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8

Currently I have a need to place a 'back' button within my application. This is not to replace the hardware back button, but to go back to a previous state of an item if the user does not wish to continue with his or her change of an item. Currently I have the following xaml for my MainPage, which binds an image as well as places the 'back' button on the view as well.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="MainPageGrid" Margin="{Binding}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="currentPhoto" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="12,0,12,12" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"/>
                <Button x:Name="photoRefreshButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" 
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"  Click="photoRefreshButton_Click"
                        toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                    <Image Source="Assets/Buttons/back.png"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
```

I would like to be able to toggle the foreground and background when the button is pressed and released, but I am unsure of how to change the button template style for this. I would like to use the following setup:

```
Not Pressed
Foreground = #FF1BA1E2 (ARGB: 255, 27, 161, 226)
background = transparent

Pressed 
Foreground = Current theme foreground brush
background = transparent
```

EDIT

Trying this did not work for me

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF1BA1E2 "/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that the NotPressed state just use the default colors and not the Disable State. Also if you change the Foreground, it will change the foregroud of some text but not an image. The easier to change the "foreground" of an image is probably to put it inside a Rectangle and use an opacity mask:

```
<Style x:Key="BackButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>

        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="circleBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                         <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="circleBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Grid >
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF1BA1E2">
                                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Buttons/back.png"/>
                                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            </Rectangle>
                             <Ellipse x:Name="circleBorder" Stroke="Red"  StrokeThickness="5"/>
                               </Grid>

                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Quick question, on the `Disabled` VisualState, did you mean to completely remove the first `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>`? Also, if I was to place a circular border around the button to mimic the default app bar button scheme, would you suggest creating a single image with the back button and circle as one image, or manually placing a border around the button, and how?

Comment: Added back so that your button change foregroud when you Disable it. Also added an ellipse to show the circle "border".

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special reason you are trying to do it from XAML? IMO it's way easier to do it from codebehind. Just add these lines, edited to reflect the actual foreground/background you want, to the button's `Clicked` event handler:

```
var btn = sender as Button;
if (btn != null)
{
    btn.Foreground=.......;
    btn.Background=.......;
}
```

Comment: The only button event handler I have is the `Clicked` event. How would the above be reflected in the pressed and disabled states? I'm just trying to do it in xaml because with previous experience of modifying templates such as this it seems to work well with no code behind.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the `Clicked` event, but forgot to write that in my answer. But if you want to alternate between states on each click, it's just as easy: if (ForeGround==OriginalState) ForeGround=ModifiedState else ForeGround=OriginalState